# An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server'

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to run my angular project on another system
I copy pasted all the required files(hopefully) and when I try to run the project using `ng serve` it throws this error

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- C:\Users\acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- C:\Users\acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- C:\Users\acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
- C:\Users\acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\Users\acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\Users\acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\Users\acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- C:\Users\acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
See "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-GYuFL2\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

I searched on the web for this type of error but I didn't found any relevant post or I couldn't understand other posts

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: Try to delete the node-modules folder and run npm install .. also might be checking the angular global versions in the two environments

Comment: Thanks for the help @maxkart
It is running fine now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to delete the node-modules folder and run `npm install` .. also might be checking the angular global versions in the two environments